# PHP file() retorna � (unknown char) entre cada letra

Tags: php

Estou a fazer file() a um ficheiro e este retorna � entre cada letra do documento.

alfa.dic

```
Adão
Andy
```

Código:

```
$dictionary = file('alfa.dic', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

var_dump:

```
string '�A�d�ã�o�' (length=9)
string '�A�n�d�y�' (length=9)
```

Pensei que fosse um problema do charset mas mesmo usando `utf8_encode()` este não remove os caracteres.

Como posso limpar cada linha desses caracteres desconhecidos?

Comment: Você sabe qual o charset desse arquivo? Em qual SO você esta fazendo isso?

Comment: o charset do arquivo é `'UTF-16 LE with BOM'`

Comment: Já tentou usar iconv? iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $string_do_arquivo);

Comment: Se não, tenta mb_convert_encoding: mb_convert_encoding($string_do_arquivo , 'UTF-8' , 'UTF-16LE');

Comment: Bem, de qualquer forma, da uma olhada nessa pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980068/how-to-convert-utf-16le-to-utf-8-in-php

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta de @gabrielhof ajudou-me a perceber que o problema era o charset do ficheiro estar em `'UTF-16 LE with BOM'` em vez de `UTF8`.

Usando o editor Sublime Text 3 fui a

```
File -> Save with Encoding -> UTF8
```

E o problema ficou resolvido para a comunicação com PHP.
Obrigado

Comment: Que bom que resolveu mas eu gostaria de dar uma olhada mais de perto nesse problema mesmo assim então, seria possível você disponibilizar esse arquivo .DIC?

Comment: A partir deste site http://www.winedt.org/Dict/, basta fazer o dowload de qualquer dicionário em `UNICODE`