# Caracter estranho no início das páginas de site

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Estou desenvolvendo um site em PHP e MYSQL e todas as páginas estão exibindo os seguintes caracteres no início da página: ï»¿

Cada página (index, sobre, contato...) ao ser aberta possui no canto superior esquerdo, bem no topo, essa sujeira. Já tentei mexer em codificação das páginas, banco de dados, nada resolveu.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Coloque o código de pelo menos uma pagina

Comment: pelo que descreve, o mais próximo que posso deduzir é "utf8 bom". Remova o utf8-bom:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31971/php-file-retorna-unknown-char-entre-cada-letra/31976#31976

Answer (score 6):

Tive este problema e resolvi abrindo o arquivo PHP no Notepad++ e fui na Aba Codificação (Encoding) e salvei o arquivo em **UTF8 sem bom**.

Comment: Se vocÇe estiver usando o Dreamweaver abra a janela de "Preferências" (ctrl+u) no item novo documento e tire a seleção 'Incluir assinatura Unicode (BOM)'.

Comment: Obrigado. Resolvi definindo a codiicação de cada arquivo como UTF-8. Com isso comecei a ter erros ao exibir na tela informações vindas do banco. Mesmo o banco de dados estando codificado em utf-8. Coloquei um "utf8_encode($variavel)" antes de 'printar' qualquer conteúdo e resolveu.